# Maps not loading when app compiled on Windows

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem with a simple map viewer app. For some reason my app works fine when I upload it to an Android device via an iMac, but when I upload the exact same app from my Windows computer it loads the MapActivity, but no map tiles. So I do see the raster, and can move it around. Just no tiles.

I have the feeling it's something stupid I overlooked, but those things are often the most annoying to find.

I also checked the Google Maps API key, but came to the conclusion that debugging keys are the same on different computers, so that didn't matter.

Any ideas?

Comment: i as well thought about the debug key being different. are you sure the debugging keys are the same? did you try to copy the debug keystore from mac to windows for testing? i don't see any other reason why this should not work.

Comment: Actually I went trough the process of getting a 'new' debug key on my windows, to be sure it would work. (getting the MD5 signature etc) But the google website returned me the exactly the same API Key as I got some time ago when I did the whole process on my mac..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I did the sign up process *another time* and got another key this time. Now it works. I don't know what went wrong before.